# An interesting mathematics task.

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of different ways of arrangement of all natural numbers from 1 to 9 inclusive, one in table cells measuring 3 by 3 such that the sum of the numbers in each row and each column are equal. The table can not be turned and reflected.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square this should get you going in figuring this out

Comment: This question is as old as the World is.

Comment: I notice that the diagonals need not add to the same thing; so perhaps this is a bit different than the more standard 'magic-square' question.

Comment: Yes, the diagonals are not in the condition.

Answer (score 1):

Observations

(1) If we add up by rows, we get a sum of $1+2+\cdots+9=45$. So each row sum (and so also each column sum) must be $15$.

(2) There are $8$ possible sums to $15$ using the distinct numbers given.  They are:

$1+5+9$

$1+6+8$

$2+4+9$

$2+5+8$

$2+6+7$

$3+4+8$

$3+5+7$

$4+5+6$

(3)  In a legal array, each number appears in two sums (one for its row and one for its column).  Because each of the numbers $1, 3, 7, 9$ each appear exactly twice in the above list; the rows and columns of the table must use the sums

$1+5+9$; $1+6+8$; $2+4+9$; $2+6+7$; $3+4+8$; and $3+5+7$.

(4) Once $1$ and its row and column are filled in, the rest of the table is determined.  There are nine choices for $1$; four choices for $5$; and two choices for $6$.  The rest of the positions are determined.  For example
$$\begin{matrix}5&?&?\\1&?&6\\?&?&? \end{matrix}$$
leads to 
$$\begin{matrix}5&3&7\\1&8&6\\9&4&2 \end{matrix}$$

Hence there are $9\cdot 4\cdot 2=72$ possible placements, although this counts rotations and reflections.  So this leads to $\frac{72}{8}=9$ possibilities if rotations and reflections are not counted separately.

It is interesting to note that given an arrangement; one may permute rows (6 ways); permute columns (6 ways); and do matrix transposition or not do matrix transposition (2 ways).  So given one arrangement all other arrangements are obtained by row permutations, column permutations, and matrix transposition.